# The word problem for groups preceded PH Theorem as a practical undecidability result

Tags: group-theory, logic, incompleteness, combinatorics-on-words

The Paris-Harrington theorem is often cited as the first practical instance of an undecidable problem since it doesn't depend on self-reference or diagonalization and is an interesting mathematical question in its own right. But why isn't [the unsolvability of the word problem on groups](https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.44.10.1061) considered for that distinction? It came two decades before PH theorem. Am I misunderstanding some subtle difference between the two ideas? Or is PH overshadowing the unsolvability for the word problem on groups in the history of undecidability logic?

Answer (score 8):

You're conflating undecidability in the *proof-theoretic* sense (= **independence**) with undecidability in the *algorithmic* sense (= **incomputability**). These are related but distinct notions. The relationship between the two is discussed at some length [at MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130789/are-the-two-meanings-of-undecidable-related). Note that there is further terminological "bleed" between the two topics - e.g. "diagonalization" a la the unsolvability of the Halting Problem or a la the [diagonal lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma) - so one has to be careful.

Here are two important notes:

- Independence is always *relative to a background theory*, while incomputability is absolute. Strictly speaking, we shouldn't say for example that the Godel(-Rosser) sentence is independent - rather, the GR-sentence *of an appropriate theory $T$* is independent *of that same theory $T$*.

  - OK fine, in some - usually older - logic papers and books you will find the phrase "absolutely undecidable" or similar. But this refers to the **fundamentally vague** notion of "independent of any 'reasonable' base theory" (what does 'reasonable' mean exactly?), and moreover seems to have fallen out of favor.
- Incomputability does yield instances of independence! Knowing that there is a finitely presented group $G=\langle A\vert R\rangle$ with incomputable word problem tells us (for instance) that if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is arithmetically sound then there is some word on $A$ which is not $R$-trivial but which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ cannot prove is not $R$-trivial; moreover, looking at the proof of the undecidability of the word problem we can even whip up a specific example word. However, this example will not be particularly natural. Moreover, this is really only a one-way phenomenon, since in general there is no way to attach a decision problem to a *single* sentence.

Getting back to your original post, the point about PH is that it represents a **single yes/no question** which is reasonably natural and carries no obvious "logical baggage" but which is independent from first-order Peano arithmetic.